# I have to cells, A1 and B1, I want to display the value of A1 or B1 when either cell have value entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two cells, A1 and A2, I want to display the value of A1 or A2 in cell B1 when either cell have value entered. how do I create the formula for cell B1?

Comment: What if both have values?

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint: see the IF and ISBLANK functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A2)
```

This formula will only return nonblank cells (because of the 'TRUE' argument). If both cells are nonblank, it will return both values seperated by a comma, (because of the '", "' argument)

Alternatively if you want to only return one cell even if both were occupied, you could prioritize A1 like this.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),A2,A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the following should serve:

```
=A1&A2
```

where TEXTJOIN is not available.

[Questions tagged with `excel` should be version-agnostic.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info)